# Ограничение по количеству выбранных свойств при редактировании элемента инфоблока в Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

**Задача:**
У элемента инфоблока есть 6 пользовательских свойств. Все свойства имеют тип Список, внешний вид - Флажки и одно значение XML_ID - YES, Значение- Да. Все эти 6 свойств объединены в вкладку "Лейблы" (screen_1)[image: screen_1]

Нужно сделать, чтобы при создании/редактировании инфоблока контент-менеджер мог выбрать не больше трех флажков. Если выбраны больше трех флажков показывает ошибку "Можно выбрать не больше трех флажков"

```
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate", Array("LableLimit", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdateLabelLimit"));

class LableLimit {

    public function OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdateLabelLimit(&$arFields)
    {
        $db_props = CIBlockElement::GetProperty($arFields['IBLOCK_ID'], $arFields['ID'], "sort", "asc", array());
        $PROPS = [];
        while($ar_props = $db_props->Fetch()){
            if(strpos($ar_props['CODE'],'LABEL') !== false){
                $PROPS[$ar_props['CODE']] = $ar_props['VALUE'];
            }
        }

        if (count($PROPS) > 3){

            global $APPLICATION;
            $APPLICATION->ThrowException("Error");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть обработчики событий в на добавление `OnAfterIBlockElementAdd` и редактирование `OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate` элементов инфоблока можно использовать их и проверять наши свойства и если более трех активных чекбоксов то выдавать ошибку и не сохранять изменение элемента. Пример кода в init.php нужно добавить код
`AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate", Array("MyClass", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdateHandler"));
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnAfterIBlockElementAdd", Array("MyClass", "OnAfterIBlockElementAddUpdateHandler"));
class MyClass
{
    function OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdateHandler(&$arFields)
    {
        //в $arFields проверяем наши свойства на активность
        // вывод ошибку
        global $APPLICATION;
        $APPLICATION->throwException("У вас более 3 активных чекбокса");
        // выходим из функции API тем самым не сохраняем изменения
        return false;
    }
    function OnAfterIBlockElementAddUpdateHandler(&$arFields)
    {
        //в $arFields проверяем наши свойства на активность
        // вывод ошибку
        global $APPLICATION;
        $APPLICATION->throwException("У вас более 3 активных чекбокса");
        // выходим из функции API тем самым не сохраняем изменения
        return false;
    }
}`

Comment: При использовании события OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate столкнулся со следующим поведением. При изменении количества галочек (с ошибочных четырех на положенные три) во входящем массиве $arFields ни чего не изменяется т.е. во входящем массиве стоят отмеченные четыре свойства.

Comment: @MasterMiMiKi а вы по ссылке принимаете $arFields в метод ?

Comment: Да, по ссылке.
&$arFields

Comment: приложите свой код, тогда можно будет что то вам сказать.

Comment: Приложил к описанию своей задачи

Comment: я бы вам посоветовал вам сделать проверку на IBLOCK_ID что бы не делать обработку на всех инфоблоках. Так же зачем вы тащите свойства через API если они у вас есть в $arFields и вы его можете менять напрямую и изменения будут сохранены сразу